# Rubyで undefined method `table' for CSV:Class (NoMethodError) というエラーが発生する

Tags: ruby, csv

以下のコードを実行した時，
game.rb:3: undefined method `table' for CSV:Class (NoMethodError)
というようなエラーが出ます．

どうすればエラーの対処することができるでしょうか．
rubyファイル（game.rb）

```
require 'csv'

csv = CSV.table('data.csv')

time = csv[:time]  #ヘッダーを指定する場合

puts time.class # => array
puts time # => 10:00
          #    20:00
          #    03:00

one = csv[1] #行を指定する場合
puts one.class # => CSV::Row
puts one # => 20:10,GOODNIGHT,miki
puts one[:time] # => 20:10
```

csvファイル（data.csv）

```
time,text,user
10:00,Hello,tarou
20:10,GOODNIGHT,miki
03:00,SINTYOKUDAME,se
```

Comment: 使用しているrubyのバージョンは何ですか？ 1.9 以降のバージョンを使用してみて下さい。

Comment: rubyバージョンが1.87でした．プログラミング初心者で申し訳ないのですが，バージョンアップさせる方法教えてもいただきないでしょうか．
または，1.87で可能なコードにするにはどこをどのように修正すればよいですか

Comment: 1.8.7 ではtable メソッドはありません。標準ライブラリを使うという意味では新しいバージョンのrubyを使う必要があります。 ライブラリのバージョンアップというより、新しいバージョンのrubyをインストールすればいいかと思います。

Comment: @ando-rei OS名とバージョンぐらいは書かないとアドバイスできないと思いますよ。[Rubyのインストール](https://www.ruby-lang.org/ja/documentation/installation/)

Answer (score 1):

コメントでやりとりされているとおり、Rubyのバージョンが古いのが原因です。
質問のコードはRuby 1.9以上で動作しますが、1.9系もメンテナンスが終了しているので、最低でも2.0以上にアップデートした方がいいと思います。（現時点の最新版である2.2.3を使うのが理想的）

バージョンアップの方法ですが、最近ではrbenv（もしくはRVM）を使って任意のバージョンに切り替えられるようにするのが主流です。
参考までにrbenvの公式ページをリンクしておきます。

https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv

ネットを検索すると日本語の情報もたくさん見つかると思うので、それらを参考にして以下のように作業を進めてみてください。

1. rbenvのインストール
2. Ruby 2.2.3のインストール（rbenvを使用）
3. rbenvでバージョンを切り替え、Ruby 2.2.3上でgame.rbを実行